# I have deleted python but still can't re-install from an installer

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-xp

So I was trying to get rid of python because I moved to raspberry pi 3b. I uninstalled python by uninstalling every python related file which I believe is the problem. When I tried to redownload python from python.org, it asked me to either repair, change, or remove python. I tried all of these but the action always rolls back saying "A network error occurred while attempting to read from file: [Location of the installer]". I'm on windows XP. The command prompt doesn't recognize python as a command either.

Comment: The error suggests you are having network issues that are unrelated to the fact that you uninstalled. Are you using the web-installer?

Comment: I am using a web installer. It's the one you download from the website, right? I downloaded the python34 msi file

Comment: There are several types on the site, the web installer requires a network connection and can give these errors but there's also a standalone installer

Comment: Either that or you're installing from another computer on your network, in which case, don't

Comment: I couldn't find the standalone installer, where is it?